# How/where to check reputation loss?

Tags: discussion, reputation

According to [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation):

> You lose reputation when:
>
> - your question is voted down: −2
> - your answer is voted down: −2
> - you vote down an answer: −1
> - you place a bounty on a question: − full bounty amount
> - one of your posts receives 6 spam or offensive flags: −100

I know that I have lost a few reputation points in the last 24 hours, however it is not reflected when I checked the "Reputation board" (don't know if it has a more appropriate name), I only see reputation points gained.

Where can I have a look at the reputation lost points?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is based on privilege or not, but could you see "show removed post" at the bottom of [your reputation](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/247431/reddy-lutonadio?tab=reputation)?

Comment: No, I haven't seen it.

Answer (score 3):

You do not have the privilege to [view deleted posts](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)  as of now, otherwise, you could have figured this out yourself. In the last 24 hours, you suffered a loss of 4 points in total, accrued from two suggested edits earlier. The two posts, both questions actually, have been deleted by Community user as part of  [deleting abandoned questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/286110). Those two questions were earlier closed, one for being off-topic and the other being unclear, and didn't meet the criteria to stay visible. Deleting a post removes points gained from a suggested edit for that post.

Tip: avoid editing *blatantly [off-topic posts](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)* (programming/development related questions), unless for removing personal information, since they should either be closed or be deleted. There is no good reason to improve them.

Comment: That explains it. Shouldn't losing points due to deleted/closed questions be included in the answer to the questions (link) posted in the OP?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio in this case, you didn't really lose the reputation, but your gained reputation was *undone*. This is the same case as getting +1 rep back when an answer you downvoted gets deleted.

Comment: @AndrewT.:-) Thanks for the explanation.